# What's the Allocation Base shown in the "address" command of windbg?

Tags: windbg

When you use `!address` command to find the module that owns an memory address, it shows both a `Allocation Base` and `Base Address`.

So `Allocation Base` is where the DLL image gets loaded (same as the output of the `lm` command), what about the `Base Address` then?

Answer (score 2):

AllocationBase refers the start address of the allocated block in memory.
This block can hold segments of different types.
When checking for a specific address, the base address will tell you where the block it belongs to starts and the base address will point to the segment start address.

Check this link, a great tutorial from MSDN:
[Memory User Mode Tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-21-WinDbg-Memory-User-Mode)